# Tableview goes empty when I want to scroll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableview with a custom tableview cell. It loads the tableview with the data. But when I try to scroll it goes empty. I am adding this tableview to another view like this. it is loaded after I push a button.

```
-(IBAction)chooseFirstController:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *nextController = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstController" bundle:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:nextController.view];

}
```

And for my tableview I have this methods.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"StaffCustomCell";
        StaffCustomCell *cell = (StaffCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StafCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        Staff *staff = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.lblName.text = staff.name;
        cell.lblGeboortePlaats.text = staff.birthplace;
        cell.lblGeboorteDatum.text = staff.birthday;

       return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];


    return count;



}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];

    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

Can anybody help ?

Kind regards.

**EDIT**

Here you see my staffCustomCell.m

```
#import "StaffCustomCell.h"

@implementation StaffCustomCell

@synthesize lblContract         = _lblContract;
@synthesize lblDebuut           = _lblDebuut;
@synthesize lblFunction         = _lblFunction;
@synthesize lblGeboorteDatum    = _lblGeboorteDatum;
@synthesize lblGeboortePlaats   = _lblGeboortePlaats;
@synthesize lblKinderen         = _lblKinderen;
@synthesize lblName             = _lblName;
@synthesize lblNationaliteit    = _lblNationaliteit;
@synthesize lblPartner          = _lblPartner;
@synthesize lblVorigeClubsS     = _lblVorigeClubsS;
@synthesize lblVorigeClubsT     = _lblVorigeClubsT;
@synthesize imgTrainer          = _imgTrainer;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: could you show the implementation of StaffCustomCell. How do you implement - (void)prepareForReuse method?

Comment: @user1090590 the .M file of StaffCustomCell?

Comment: yes, in particular cause of the issue can be in - (void)prepareForReuse  method.

Comment: @user1090590 what should i put in this method ?

Comment: your code looks good. How it goes empty, while scrolling or simultaneously?

Comment: @NeverBe When I want to scroll it goes empty. It doesn't scroll

Comment: i supposed self.contentView or nextController.view released. Can you check it?

Comment: What do you mean by released ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your IBAction method, you aren't using a property for nextController, so it will be deallocated as soon as that method goes out of scope. Create a property (typed strong) for nextController, and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you scroll, it will not reload as you have just added nextController's view.
one solution is to add tableview and its delegate method in same class and just hide it in viewdidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

and on IBAction

```
tableView.hidden = NO;
[tableView reloadData];
```

after using somewhere and hide it again.
hopefully this will solve you problem.